# auto property get and set is not working inside callback method c#

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Hi I am simply trying to get the value from a static auto property as below -

Here is my class -

```
public class ShutdownService
{
  private const int TimerInterval = 6000;
  private static DateTime _midnightStartTime;

  public static bool TimeForMidNightShutDown{get; set;}

  public static void Start(){
   _midnightStartTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(4);
   _timer = new Timer(StartTask, null, 0, TimerInterval);
  }

  public static void StartTask(object state){
    if(DateTime.Now >= _midnightStartTime){
      TimeForMidNightShutDown = true;
    } else {
      TimeForMidNightShutDown = false;
    } 
  }
}
```

I am calling this start method when I am starting the application. if I put a debug point on `if(DateTime.Now >= _midnightStartTime)`, it's making `TimeForMidNightShutDown` property value as true. But when I call this property from other class by `ShutdownService.TimeForMidNightShutDown`, it's always returning me as false. I am not sure what am I missing here. Could you please guide?

Comment: Any reason why you didn't declare the class static?

Comment: @RandRandom I am working on this existing class on my project. hence didn't declare it as static. But will that lead me to solution? Appreciate your help

Comment: Why don't you set a breakpoint on your setter and see where it gets set to the value you don't like?

Comment: IMHO your problem can't be solved because you aren't showing the problem, if I would put your code into a dummy application your described behaviour wouldn't reproduce.

Comment: Here a screenshot of your code working as I would expect - https://i.stack.imgur.com/svMLQ.png

Comment: @RandRandom I see but you have called the StartTask method directly. Can you call this by ShutdownService.start() ?

Comment: Same result - https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAOsy.png

Comment: In my case there is a background thread which  gets triggered in every 5 mins and check this value. I guess then this thread is the culprit and setting the value as false. I need to dig more then. Thank you for your quick check. means a lot. Thank you so much

Comment: Yeah, something different is going on that we don't know. As you can see here, even a background thread doesn't produce your problem. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXDZZ.png

Comment: As @nvoigt already mentioned you could just simply add a breakpoint to the setter, to avoid hitting the breakpoint multiple times I would suggest changing your code to this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNQCz.png (the lock is used to make the setter thread safe) - with this breakpoint you should get the change from true to false and find the culprit

Comment: @RandRandom Yeah I have tried the same and then it hit the breakpoint when the flag became true. Then where I am checking  (ShutdownService.TimeForMidNightShutDown), the value became false without hitting that breakpoint. bit weird. Still trying to figure it out what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know why the static stuff is not working. So instead of offering wrong clues I would like to give you a working example without using static, which maybe caused your problem:

```
public class ShutdownService
{
    private const int TimerInterval = 6000;
    private DateTime _midnightStartTime;
    private bool disposerFlag;

    public bool TimeForMidNightShutDown{get; set;}

    public void Start(){
        _midnightStartTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
        var _timer = new Timer(StartTask, null, 0, TimerInterval);
        while (!disposerFlag)
        {
            
        }

        _timer.Dispose();
    }

    public void StartTask(object state)
    {
        if(DateTime.Now >= _midnightStartTime)
        {
            TimeForMidNightShutDown = true;
            Console.WriteLine("true");
            disposerFlag = true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            TimeForMidNightShutDown = false;
            Console.WriteLine("false");
        } 
    }
}
```

This code can be than executed over the Programm.cs in the main method with

```
new ShutdownService().Start();
```

The empty while loop is quite important since the programm won't wait for the timer to finish his duty. I am sure you could also solve it way more elegant with some async approach or also with static, but this is one fast working model here. Hope it helps. And I am totally open here for improvements.

Comment: Thank you @Patrick for your comment. Let me try this on my machine and let you know the result. Appreciate you help and effort.